# Transferring strings containing emotions to server

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, playframework

On my website whenever a user enters a mobile emoji like  into an input field it will be saved as ?? in my database.

Those emojis are encoded in utf8mb4, so I already updated my database collation to utf8mb4_general_ci.

While the emoticons can be saved successfully now when transfering the message containing a emoji from a client to my server, it still get's somewhere changed into ?? and I am now trying to figure out where and how to solve it.

Sending the message to my server happens in this ajax call:

```
function updateStatus() {
    var status = $("#status").val();

    jsRoutes.controllers.Userdata.updateStatus( status ).ajax({
        success : function(data) {
              $("#profil").cftoaster({content: data});
        },
        error : function(err) {
              $("#profil").cftoaster({content: err.responseText});
        }
    });
}
```

On serverside I am using java based Play Framework 2.4.4.
This is the beginning of the method which is called in the ajax call:

```
public static Result updateStatus(String status) {

        String receivedName = Application.getSessionUser();
        Logger.debug("RecvStatus: " + status);
        ...

}
```

The Logger output already is `??` for an emoticon.

The route looks like this:

```
PUT         /status/                          controllers.Userdata.updateStatus(status: String)
```

**EDIT:**

To make sure the transfer from client to server is alright I am now transferring the actual unicode values, I change my server function like this

```
Logger.debug("RecvStatus: " + status);
status = status.replace("\\","");
String[] arr = status.split("u");
status = "";
for(int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
    int hexVal = Integer.parseInt(arr[i], 16);
    status += (char)hexVal;
}
Logger.debug("RecvStatus: " + status);
```

and get the following output:

```
[debug] application - RecvStatus: \ud83d\ude01
[debug] application - RecvStatus: ?
```

which means the problem is probably with java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for anyone having a similiar problem here my workaround.

First I tried to convert the String in java to base64 and store it this way. Unfortunately after decoding the base64 the unicode information still got lost and ?? was shown instead of emoticons.

What I than did was converting the received String into unicode and than into base64, and when I load the Strings from the database I first decode base64 and then convert the unicode information into an actual String. This way the emoticons are stored and afterwards shown correctly.